# Proving differentiability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to do Spivak's Calculus on Manifold excersise 2-4. It goes as follows:

> Let $g$ be a continuous real valued function on the unit circle $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2:||x||=1\}$ such that $g(0,1)=g(1,0)=0$ and $g(-x)=-g(x)$. Define $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}||x||g\left( \frac{x}{||x||}\right),&x\neq0 \\ 0, & x=0 \end{cases}$$
>   Define $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $h(t) =f(tx)$ and show that $h$ is differentiable but $f$ isn't.

I've been having a huge confussion by this in the last days and it seems there is something I'm skipping, because I had no idea of how to use the former properties of $g$ -at least $g$ were linear which doesn't seem to be necessarilly the case- to prove differentiability.

So, basically I should found $\lambda:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{h(t+\alpha)-h(t)-\lambda(\alpha)}{\alpha} = \lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{f(tx+\alpha x)-h(tx)-\lambda(\alpha)}{\alpha}=0$$

By definition of $f$ this gives

$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{||x||||t+\alpha ||g\left( \frac{x(t+\alpha)}{||x||||t+\alpha||}\right)-||t||||x||g\left(\frac{tx}{||t||||x||}\right)-\lambda(\alpha)}{\alpha}= $$

Since $x$ isn't a variable of the limit I could as well write

$$||x||\lim_{\alpha\to 0} \frac{||t+\alpha ||g\left( \frac{x(t+\alpha)}{||x||||t+\alpha||}\right)-||t||g\left(\frac{tx}{||t||||x||}\right)-\lambda(\alpha)}{\alpha}=0$$

Both vector inside $g$ have norm $1$, but how could I use $g(1,0)=g(0,1)=0$ without introducing the linearility of $g$ as a new condition?

Hints?.

Comment: So do I understand correctly, you say you have already shown that $h$ *is* differentiable? And your trouble lies in showing that $f$ is not?

Comment: I haven't shown that $f$ is differentiable because I haven't found $\lambda$, which I don't know how to define in order to be the last limit true.

Comment: I don't quite follow your line of thought. $f$ not being differentiable means there does **not** exist a linear map such that the obvious differential quotient goes to $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad but in the last comment I meant to say $h$; I haven't found why $h$ is differentiable because I don't know to could I define $\lambda$.
Spivak asks to prove that $h$ is differentiable even if $f$ isn't.

Comment: Okay. So $h$ is just a simple 1-D real-valued function, so I suggest you just calculate it and simply look at it whether it's differentiable.

Comment: Work with the usual definition for 1-D was my first attempt, it didn't go work out a lot better for me because after a few steps I'd have $\lim_{\alpha->0}=\frac{h(t+\alpha)-h(t)}{\alpha}= \lim_{\alpha->0}=\frac{f(x(t+\alpha)-f(xt)}{\alpha} = \lim_{\alpha->0}=\frac{||x||||t+\alpha||g\left(\frac{x(t+ \alpha)}{||x||||t+ \alpha||}\right)-||x||||t||g\left(\frac{tx}{||t||||x||}\right)}{\alpha}$ which is where I'm stuck. I used de definition above hoping to use $||t+\alpha||\leq ||t||+||\alpha||$ but it didn't seem but in the end didn't seem to be useful at all.

Comment: What I meant was: Do NOT try to blindly use the definition of differentiability. Calculate explicitly WHAT is $h$ ? You will see it is very trivially differentiable.